# Dropdownlist and highlight effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dropdownlist that I'm trying to highlight with this:

```
$('#album').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
```

My dropdown changes it's color but the color doesn't change back. If I try the method with a div, it works, so I guess the method isn't really for dropdowns, but is there any similar method for them?

Comment: I dont think the option param is needed on this.  you should be able to just simply `$('#album').effect("highlight", 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight works just fine on a dropdown with or without the options parameter.  Check out this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/py7B8/1/

Do you have something else going on in your code?  Can you reproduce the issue in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Huh strange. This line from my css was bugging it: background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);   Thanks!